# Rate limit issues (52,000 requests) when trying to connect to web viewers

Tags: oauth, instagram

Found a few posts somewhat similar to this, but never to the extent I'm getting.  And often times from the developers standpoint and not the end-user.  I'm able to log into instagram, both on my computer and on my phone just fine.  But when I try to connect to either webstagram or statigram I get this error during the auth process

{"code": 420, "error_type": "OAuthRateLimitException", "error_message": "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 52447 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum request limit is set at 5000 requests per hour."}

That's a lot of requests...and it'll keep going up then drop down to the 30,000s and start over.  Is something fishy going on here, or is there some sort of simple answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the way webstagram or statigram is logging users, it happens if they are using `client_id` to make API requests instead of `access_token`, which will not work since using `client_id` is limited to 5000 api calls per hour. When do you actually see this error? steps? Can you login using [gramfeed.com](http://gramfeed.com) ?